# Simplelightbox not working on google photos

Tags: jquery, html, css

SimpleLightbox is not working on images from google photos, when I open an image the browser just redirects me to the original google photos link, instead of opening the image in lightbox. Images from any other source do work.

I don't know what to do or what to try, I already tried to replace the images with ones that are not from google photos and then lightbox does work. But as soon a i use images from google photos, I instead get redirected to the original place were the photos are stored.

```js
$(function() {
  var gallery = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
});
```

```css
.gallery a img {
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplelightbox/1.12.1/simplelightbox.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="https://photos.google.com/u/0/album/AF1QipNP8MDRNfn3ijCBBA4lCfgMSNcFtGRrt4rqJgct/photo/AF1QipOTanJ7SMYTyDPQYByrDbAMZpRcco2xfZdeeiXK">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HDbt-jgEY_A-4uIuf17_fMiGtpMJFeceMzbYtqZaEa4tzxuKF-Eo8lsscrAkctKY4tEK05-HJBlRYYEAAI-aqkiQ1yEydJZz-ehg98F-CHDeqYzaF5k64NQZ5PP0KhTGK9akXfY3hDlMAMe0cqq2W1HY-izuAxbKnM8I7YOqLLY96OZc__ck0wLSrIAeKUcVtPsMK3NhBRugKr2Klfz6BTcDKIek19vUt42nZEbhw8EEk882yUeeGkciR42f6OQ218gv6GqsZTpvz95Ls6zsFJLJe5L3IhhKw0MPWXS7EvMada7RXxk94BnEQ26EmUN5SbXxHPTZyW0IjQlzt_wcyRYHLZn0re6pDv8CJ0KVeZ6gjZpPlbN8JoRCCblGp9t_igdB15nFXdfUxy8b1BJbCnZR9UD22JKAfNzKNVMIxQQB6ocI3IsZX8xe_pYA5EYIGavmFa6_7EDbarSDSNi6cFPhSve-3RBpxILiitHFufjtnlux3sZzBIVgXUV8LmK4hOn0DQQuPdqyW6audVniaT49ExUyho7wcyXd14VnKi13djLsyoqQRFf2PGHgbxbVqL5kttU1ZHxMgbrJd0mS2KrOPwwEI5ZV3KzRostriXVg1S03SyHAEICR0OuLDc4tJ-AzzdY3oPMz6koiCbFj6_PvvVElY0w=w1124-h843-no"
        alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/w0D6oBq9pp-VTckCjS0m1os98IYxo-Sh2ukekaHGpktJxVsdtc01rHBz_VLHeU97nuUSTDBv49-x70nMwA1JHENTC_aBO5gQ0iSqzgavirjak4qEJCuPkJ1X4CETMXSivKgrZuQ5eNVoVQkkQyxvgK7bsYgNudhtghN4lG_aFphPa1gmJa16k8hXs61PR0McdbwcJY7X94AaAH8jm9lEKjGf4SxGDnegPm91UypuzHsnIrSUyJBdpxrxW5Wddt_bS_Bs8HSoWuy8XXOKkG8FyW5SbTwV7-vaydF9Pi5EFEQPrhJvbLZllrem4M8bj0IJACBMHmwPhA06U27juPjx5RWTSdK1kifc-HIqXFxNMg2JRn5PHrEjEarjaQ3v86Pvpr9gWJSf_BQwBtLAfVOOqXLz-zPCsvk0b51KkLnTC81phbOyE7knDDoODkwvJ1AM3EhsafhSysutuvgZjDmEP1YdgAr8_PyW4vOlaRAgujIvqNqJpcBmU0QKtiCFSDXOCd35Ek9s4D6UwACfOntFr02C_mm-iW056g5DZtR6NyxzqK0esvrIb0G9L-2b3r-AmBob-QGyK60cWCl8FAnsr57jjklcQ0ZSxgKCsCrspE9EZaaAnNqdHZRi_4edMVOsk3Md0-n78N1XVUQie-XwOLsNRPW3ogI=w633-h843-no">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/w0D6oBq9pp-VTckCjS0m1os98IYxo-Sh2ukekaHGpktJxVsdtc01rHBz_VLHeU97nuUSTDBv49-x70nMwA1JHENTC_aBO5gQ0iSqzgavirjak4qEJCuPkJ1X4CETMXSivKgrZuQ5eNVoVQkkQyxvgK7bsYgNudhtghN4lG_aFphPa1gmJa16k8hXs61PR0McdbwcJY7X94AaAH8jm9lEKjGf4SxGDnegPm91UypuzHsnIrSUyJBdpxrxW5Wddt_bS_Bs8HSoWuy8XXOKkG8FyW5SbTwV7-vaydF9Pi5EFEQPrhJvbLZllrem4M8bj0IJACBMHmwPhA06U27juPjx5RWTSdK1kifc-HIqXFxNMg2JRn5PHrEjEarjaQ3v86Pvpr9gWJSf_BQwBtLAfVOOqXLz-zPCsvk0b51KkLnTC81phbOyE7knDDoODkwvJ1AM3EhsafhSysutuvgZjDmEP1YdgAr8_PyW4vOlaRAgujIvqNqJpcBmU0QKtiCFSDXOCd35Ek9s4D6UwACfOntFr02C_mm-iW056g5DZtR6NyxzqK0esvrIb0G9L-2b3r-AmBob-QGyK60cWCl8FAnsr57jjklcQ0ZSxgKCsCrspE9EZaaAnNqdHZRi_4edMVOsk3Md0-n78N1XVUQie-XwOLsNRPW3ogI=w633-h843-no"
        alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jj282J7NDrB4NsNqOYmukfR3z63ZFxY2zSEeapkD2zMeaRm0JyJp_BpRA6KHHt_O6SwcGYe_4S_FZDymrIM_FwkvN_HB4y4rRmj7VmX97ic5SY_8597i0WJSqL11wZOPQxh97N__lvsYo9cayaJguCB1i4qjgc_nI1pMHwMCTbpt-AByv4iGdsgFICyqM0y6MbuI5r1xr8Y1k8z0wYvWz4OVJK3hzYPKeFbd1qTfUUKdG3PnTQ4WBo8XBPmeJUkJ8DxFTj0sGFnaHh7pb6EjUkE7z51pA-mvuvnN9pWWbMfpJpDKsyYkN6LrJfolHD9OxnMLlef_oLcGdiGyDA-lHHKcbHCLzVqVU_4U33JueT0CFLh7stMGlXnSVXkQpXF9fjJK6yiq07o9n2RYnyYyClZ5XTv1who79jmA69cyYK91GeKxzhtsPsNKD2HvVQwomcgGt6_Lq6q0OoSwVGDWkVwmtmY3kCttahjoOt6NGnP9lll8IGD0hH_iunXAPJAFQjrdwlkFMYnRbJcLDoubByzXfQE1Ox_RV_XG8C_CIzDnHPSMMff3eEv2qSkSbELcWNxaVF29QwI5Qd3LyyY8m7_L300IhRibN_DJL7L_hVvIIw5mHRiSQCTuQ9Ig2pi7rKvrcaUBMtq_6YVAnITUomt9oZiulLU=w633-h843-no">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jj282J7NDrB4NsNqOYmukfR3z63ZFxY2zSEeapkD2zMeaRm0JyJp_BpRA6KHHt_O6SwcGYe_4S_FZDymrIM_FwkvN_HB4y4rRmj7VmX97ic5SY_8597i0WJSqL11wZOPQxh97N__lvsYo9cayaJguCB1i4qjgc_nI1pMHwMCTbpt-AByv4iGdsgFICyqM0y6MbuI5r1xr8Y1k8z0wYvWz4OVJK3hzYPKeFbd1qTfUUKdG3PnTQ4WBo8XBPmeJUkJ8DxFTj0sGFnaHh7pb6EjUkE7z51pA-mvuvnN9pWWbMfpJpDKsyYkN6LrJfolHD9OxnMLlef_oLcGdiGyDA-lHHKcbHCLzVqVU_4U33JueT0CFLh7stMGlXnSVXkQpXF9fjJK6yiq07o9n2RYnyYyClZ5XTv1who79jmA69cyYK91GeKxzhtsPsNKD2HvVQwomcgGt6_Lq6q0OoSwVGDWkVwmtmY3kCttahjoOt6NGnP9lll8IGD0hH_iunXAPJAFQjrdwlkFMYnRbJcLDoubByzXfQE1Ox_RV_XG8C_CIzDnHPSMMff3eEv2qSkSbELcWNxaVF29QwI5Qd3LyyY8m7_L300IhRibN_DJL7L_hVvIIw5mHRiSQCTuQ9Ig2pi7rKvrcaUBMtq_6YVAnITUomt9oZiulLU=w633-h843-no"
        alt="">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- lightbox for gallery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplelightbox/1.16.2/simple-lightbox.min.js"></script>
```

I expect simpleLightbox to open a model displaying the image and then being able to click on the next arrow to display the image next. What Im getting with this code is just redirection to the original page google page of the photo.

Answer (score 0):

That script may be outdated or requires a very specific jQuery version. I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything. Instead, using the [jsdelivr CDN](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-lightbox@2.1.0/src/simpleLightbox.min.js) seems to work well

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-lightbox@2.1.0/src/simpleLightbox.min.js`

```js
$(function() {
  var gallery = $('.gallery a').simpleLightbox();
});
```

```css
.gallery a img {
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simplelightbox/1.16.2/simplelightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="https://photos.google.com/u/0/album/AF1QipNP8MDRNfn3ijCBBA4lCfgMSNcFtGRrt4rqJgct/photo/AF1QipOTanJ7SMYTyDPQYByrDbAMZpRcco2xfZdeeiXK">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HDbt-jgEY_A-4uIuf17_fMiGtpMJFeceMzbYtqZaEa4tzxuKF-Eo8lsscrAkctKY4tEK05-HJBlRYYEAAI-aqkiQ1yEydJZz-ehg98F-CHDeqYzaF5k64NQZ5PP0KhTGK9akXfY3hDlMAMe0cqq2W1HY-izuAxbKnM8I7YOqLLY96OZc__ck0wLSrIAeKUcVtPsMK3NhBRugKr2Klfz6BTcDKIek19vUt42nZEbhw8EEk882yUeeGkciR42f6OQ218gv6GqsZTpvz95Ls6zsFJLJe5L3IhhKw0MPWXS7EvMada7RXxk94BnEQ26EmUN5SbXxHPTZyW0IjQlzt_wcyRYHLZn0re6pDv8CJ0KVeZ6gjZpPlbN8JoRCCblGp9t_igdB15nFXdfUxy8b1BJbCnZR9UD22JKAfNzKNVMIxQQB6ocI3IsZX8xe_pYA5EYIGavmFa6_7EDbarSDSNi6cFPhSve-3RBpxILiitHFufjtnlux3sZzBIVgXUV8LmK4hOn0DQQuPdqyW6audVniaT49ExUyho7wcyXd14VnKi13djLsyoqQRFf2PGHgbxbVqL5kttU1ZHxMgbrJd0mS2KrOPwwEI5ZV3KzRostriXVg1S03SyHAEICR0OuLDc4tJ-AzzdY3oPMz6koiCbFj6_PvvVElY0w=w1124-h843-no"
        alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/w0D6oBq9pp-VTckCjS0m1os98IYxo-Sh2ukekaHGpktJxVsdtc01rHBz_VLHeU97nuUSTDBv49-x70nMwA1JHENTC_aBO5gQ0iSqzgavirjak4qEJCuPkJ1X4CETMXSivKgrZuQ5eNVoVQkkQyxvgK7bsYgNudhtghN4lG_aFphPa1gmJa16k8hXs61PR0McdbwcJY7X94AaAH8jm9lEKjGf4SxGDnegPm91UypuzHsnIrSUyJBdpxrxW5Wddt_bS_Bs8HSoWuy8XXOKkG8FyW5SbTwV7-vaydF9Pi5EFEQPrhJvbLZllrem4M8bj0IJACBMHmwPhA06U27juPjx5RWTSdK1kifc-HIqXFxNMg2JRn5PHrEjEarjaQ3v86Pvpr9gWJSf_BQwBtLAfVOOqXLz-zPCsvk0b51KkLnTC81phbOyE7knDDoODkwvJ1AM3EhsafhSysutuvgZjDmEP1YdgAr8_PyW4vOlaRAgujIvqNqJpcBmU0QKtiCFSDXOCd35Ek9s4D6UwACfOntFr02C_mm-iW056g5DZtR6NyxzqK0esvrIb0G9L-2b3r-AmBob-QGyK60cWCl8FAnsr57jjklcQ0ZSxgKCsCrspE9EZaaAnNqdHZRi_4edMVOsk3Md0-n78N1XVUQie-XwOLsNRPW3ogI=w633-h843-no">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/w0D6oBq9pp-VTckCjS0m1os98IYxo-Sh2ukekaHGpktJxVsdtc01rHBz_VLHeU97nuUSTDBv49-x70nMwA1JHENTC_aBO5gQ0iSqzgavirjak4qEJCuPkJ1X4CETMXSivKgrZuQ5eNVoVQkkQyxvgK7bsYgNudhtghN4lG_aFphPa1gmJa16k8hXs61PR0McdbwcJY7X94AaAH8jm9lEKjGf4SxGDnegPm91UypuzHsnIrSUyJBdpxrxW5Wddt_bS_Bs8HSoWuy8XXOKkG8FyW5SbTwV7-vaydF9Pi5EFEQPrhJvbLZllrem4M8bj0IJACBMHmwPhA06U27juPjx5RWTSdK1kifc-HIqXFxNMg2JRn5PHrEjEarjaQ3v86Pvpr9gWJSf_BQwBtLAfVOOqXLz-zPCsvk0b51KkLnTC81phbOyE7knDDoODkwvJ1AM3EhsafhSysutuvgZjDmEP1YdgAr8_PyW4vOlaRAgujIvqNqJpcBmU0QKtiCFSDXOCd35Ek9s4D6UwACfOntFr02C_mm-iW056g5DZtR6NyxzqK0esvrIb0G9L-2b3r-AmBob-QGyK60cWCl8FAnsr57jjklcQ0ZSxgKCsCrspE9EZaaAnNqdHZRi_4edMVOsk3Md0-n78N1XVUQie-XwOLsNRPW3ogI=w633-h843-no"
        alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jj282J7NDrB4NsNqOYmukfR3z63ZFxY2zSEeapkD2zMeaRm0JyJp_BpRA6KHHt_O6SwcGYe_4S_FZDymrIM_FwkvN_HB4y4rRmj7VmX97ic5SY_8597i0WJSqL11wZOPQxh97N__lvsYo9cayaJguCB1i4qjgc_nI1pMHwMCTbpt-AByv4iGdsgFICyqM0y6MbuI5r1xr8Y1k8z0wYvWz4OVJK3hzYPKeFbd1qTfUUKdG3PnTQ4WBo8XBPmeJUkJ8DxFTj0sGFnaHh7pb6EjUkE7z51pA-mvuvnN9pWWbMfpJpDKsyYkN6LrJfolHD9OxnMLlef_oLcGdiGyDA-lHHKcbHCLzVqVU_4U33JueT0CFLh7stMGlXnSVXkQpXF9fjJK6yiq07o9n2RYnyYyClZ5XTv1who79jmA69cyYK91GeKxzhtsPsNKD2HvVQwomcgGt6_Lq6q0OoSwVGDWkVwmtmY3kCttahjoOt6NGnP9lll8IGD0hH_iunXAPJAFQjrdwlkFMYnRbJcLDoubByzXfQE1Ox_RV_XG8C_CIzDnHPSMMff3eEv2qSkSbELcWNxaVF29QwI5Qd3LyyY8m7_L300IhRibN_DJL7L_hVvIIw5mHRiSQCTuQ9Ig2pi7rKvrcaUBMtq_6YVAnITUomt9oZiulLU=w633-h843-no">
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jj282J7NDrB4NsNqOYmukfR3z63ZFxY2zSEeapkD2zMeaRm0JyJp_BpRA6KHHt_O6SwcGYe_4S_FZDymrIM_FwkvN_HB4y4rRmj7VmX97ic5SY_8597i0WJSqL11wZOPQxh97N__lvsYo9cayaJguCB1i4qjgc_nI1pMHwMCTbpt-AByv4iGdsgFICyqM0y6MbuI5r1xr8Y1k8z0wYvWz4OVJK3hzYPKeFbd1qTfUUKdG3PnTQ4WBo8XBPmeJUkJ8DxFTj0sGFnaHh7pb6EjUkE7z51pA-mvuvnN9pWWbMfpJpDKsyYkN6LrJfolHD9OxnMLlef_oLcGdiGyDA-lHHKcbHCLzVqVU_4U33JueT0CFLh7stMGlXnSVXkQpXF9fjJK6yiq07o9n2RYnyYyClZ5XTv1who79jmA69cyYK91GeKxzhtsPsNKD2HvVQwomcgGt6_Lq6q0OoSwVGDWkVwmtmY3kCttahjoOt6NGnP9lll8IGD0hH_iunXAPJAFQjrdwlkFMYnRbJcLDoubByzXfQE1Ox_RV_XG8C_CIzDnHPSMMff3eEv2qSkSbELcWNxaVF29QwI5Qd3LyyY8m7_L300IhRibN_DJL7L_hVvIIw5mHRiSQCTuQ9Ig2pi7rKvrcaUBMtq_6YVAnITUomt9oZiulLU=w633-h843-no"
        alt="">
    </a>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-lightbox@2.1.0/src/simpleLightbox.min.js"></script>
```